# How to find out if current shell was loaded by another shell?

Tags: bash, command-line

When I am in a terminal, and I type `/bin/bash`, that starts up another bash shell, right?

Is it possible to find out, via some command, whether the current bash shell has been started from another bash shell?

Also, what are the implications of starting a shell inside another? (or does it not matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whit this command you can see the parent process of the current shell:

```
ps -o comm= -p $(echo $PPID)
```

This works in `bash` where `PPID` variable is defined, don't know in other shells.

**EDIT**

As @bmk noticed, the `echo` stuff is overkill and not necessary:

```
ps -o comm= -p $PPID
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. My results: Running `ps -o comm= -p $(echo $PPID)` gives `gnome-terminal`. Running `/bin/bash`, and then `ps -o comm= -p $(echo $PPID)` gives `bash`.

Comment: What do you actually need the `echo` for? I think it should also work without it: `ps -o comm= -p $PPID`

Comment: Correct, `ps -o comm= -p $PPID` also works perfectly.

Comment: @bmk: oh yeah, I started with echo $PPID, and modified this without thinking :), -1 for enzotib

Comment: @entotib: There was nothing wrong with it (as the question was tagged with `bash`). Therefore: It works and it does what it should. It's just a bit overhead and doesn't work with different shells.

Answer (score 4):

A version that also works with shells other than `bash` is:

```
ps -p `ps h -p $$ -o ppid` -o comm=
```

Comment: Thanks. (I get the same results as I do for enzotib's answer too)

Answer (score 0):

bash actually does count that via a special, exported variable `SHLVL`.

```
$ echo "$SHLVL"
1
$ bash -c 'echo "$SHLVL"'
2
```

If SHLVL is 2 though, it doesn't necessarily mean that the parent process is bash, it just means that one of the shell's ancestors is also bash, or another process that has exported SHLVL (ksh sets it too I think).

Why do you need to know if your shell's parent is bash?

And no, there's not really any implications of running a shell inside another shell. It's just like running any other command in a shell.